# Powershell - Invoke-WebRequest - Issue with submit

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I'm working on a powershell script that will create a printer on my Company Print Server, which is all done and working.

But we have however a location where we list all used IP's, which is a webpage.

So I'm trying to use `Invoke-WebRequest` to do this. Login to the page works but then when it tries to use the form to add the IP it doesn't.

Login only has one submit button in the form and to add the IP there is three buttons. I will list them in the order they are on the page

1. Clear the form
2. Apply
3. Cancel

So I'm thinking when I `Invoke-Webrequest` it is using the "clear form" function.
Is there any way I could specify which function to use when sending a webrequest?

I cant remove the "Clear form" button since it is being used frequently, just to get that clear.

```
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://localhost -SessionVariable IP
$Form = $R.Forms[0]
$Form.fields["ctlUsername"]=User
$Form.fields["ctlPassword"]=Pass

$R=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://localhost/" + $Form.Action) -WebSession                 
$IP -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields

$D = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://localhost/addIP.php -WebSession $Test
$Form2 = $D.Forms[0]

$Form2.fields["IP"]="172.10.0.1"
$Form2.fields["name"]="Printer300"
$Form2.fields["location"]="Room407"
$Form2.fields["MAC"]="000"
$Form2.fields["ID"]="000"

Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri http://localhost/addIP.php -WebSession $IP -Method POST -Body $Form2.Fields
```

Comment: No that’s not it, just made that error when posting it here.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in terms of "filling in web pages" when it comes to sending those requests. Web pages for a human user. Filling in a form and clicking a button is the *manual* way of creating an HTTP message with data.

When you post this form:

```
IP:       [172.10.0.1          ]
Name:     [Printer300          ]
Location: [Room407             ]

[Apply] [Cancel]
```

the browser creates a text string like this:

```
IP=172.10.0.1&Name=Printer300&Location=Room407
```

and sends it to the target URL.

`Invoke-WebRequest` can create this format directly from your data. This means, you don't need to "fill in" anything. Just pass a hashtable with the proper keys and values:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost/addIP.php" -WebSession $IP -Method POST -Body @{
    IP = "172.10.0.1"
    Name = "Printer300"
    Location = "Room407"
    MAC = "000"
    ID = "000"
}
```

Of course the keys must correspond to the form field names.

---

That being said, I don't see much of a need for authentication with requests coming from the localhost. You can save yourself some busywork by disabling authentication for all local requests, and requiring it only for remote requests.

Anyway, making a website request a password and then storing that password in clear text in a script is not exactly secure to begin with.

`Invoke-WebRequest` supports Windows integrated authentication, so that you don't have to bother with usernames and passwords at all. This would be my preferred authentication solution for such tasks.

Comment: This didnt solve my problem either sadly..
I know it supports windows integration, its just in plaintext for the moment, but will be changed later when I get it to work properly to other form of authentication, it will not be windows credentials that is going to be used.

Comment: *"This didnt solve my problem either sadly."* is not actionable. What happened? Any errors?

Comment: No no errors, the script goes through like normal as it would work but it doesn’t apply the form. Could this issue be a result of a sql query?

Comment: But you control the PHP script, don't you? You can see exactly what data the server receives. For example, dump some data to the response so you can examine what the server does.

Comment: I will have access to that tomorrow when our domain admin is back at work.

Comment: In any case, if you post the form manually, i.e. with your browser, open the debugging tools (F12) of your browser and inspect the POST request that goes out. In it, you should find a string of data similar to the one shown in my answer, containing all the keys and values from the form. Look closely and make sure your PowerShell script sends the same keys. Maybe you are not sending something important.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it needed a hidden value that was not being sent via the form but was added in php function later.
Thanks for all your help.